# Spring DBUnit insert dataset before autowiring

Tags: spring, dbunit, spring-test, spring-test-dbunit

I have some beans that query the database in a `@PostConstruct` method. Thus, I need the database to be ready before autowiring occurs. Is this possible?

This is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring/app.xml",
        "classpath:spring/test-beans-context.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseSetup(value = { "/datasets/dataset1.xml", "/datasets/dataset2.xml" })
public class myTestIT {

    @Autowired
    private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;


    @Test
    public void test() {
         ...
    }

}
```

This is the bean that queries the DB inside `@PostConstruct`:

```
public class MyBean {
    @Autowire
    private SomeService someService;

    private List someList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()  {
         someList = someService.queryDB();
    }
}
```

This is an example of the class I want to test

```
public class ClassUnderTest {
    @Autowire
    private MyBean bean;


    public void methodToTest() {
        bean.getSomeList();
        // do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible. Can you show us some details?

Comment: so is classUnderTest the class that needs to query in the @PostConstruct? I don't see a MyBean anywhere. For starters, you won't be able to use the @DatabaseSetup because autowiring will happen first--you'll have to configure a org.dbunit.DataSourceDatabaseTester bean

Comment: ok, I've included more code in my question.

Comment: did you find an answer on how to do this? I have the same question, but haven't really figured out how to do it yet;

Comment: I did not find an answer to this yet

Comment: For now i solve autowiring beans in my test class and in the @before method, calling beans postconstruct method again. This is not the best way and i'm searching for a better aproach too. With Unitils i could do this =(.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, one of my service retrieve database in his @postconstruct method and thus cant find the table and breaks ...